# OWFS with Raspbian Buster

Tags: raspbian, 1wire

Installation of OWFS (one-wire-file-system) on Raspbian Buster does not succeed.

The component owserver expires the default restartSec value of 100ms on Raspberry Pi 1 and installation fails with error code 1.

```
Job for owserver.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status owserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript owserver, action "start" failed.
● owserver.service - Backend server for 1-wire control
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/owserver.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: protocol) since Thu 2020-01-02 18:24:00 CET; 181ms ago
     Docs: man:owserver(1)
  Process: 1312 ExecStart=/usr/bin/owserver -c /etc/owfs.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1312 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

systemd[1]: owserver.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: owserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
systemd[1]: Stopped Backend server for 1-wire control.
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Edit the file "/lib/systemd/system/owserver.service“ and add RestartSec=3 option.

```
[Unit]
Description=Backend server for 1-wire control
Documentation=man:owserver(1)

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
ExecStart=/usr/bin/owserver -c /etc/owfs.conf
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=3
#User=Debian-ow
#Group=Debian-ow
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Also=owserver.socket
```

Than restart the services:

systemctl daemon-reload

I hope this helps someone! Got any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the restart but I found this [link](https://github.com/owfs/owfs/issues/46) that fixed it for me. I didn't look further into it, but I'm guessing with the settings in the service file it expects the program to stay running - and not become a background process. There are other options for that case in the service file configuration.